# module in material-ui not longer found

Tags: material-ui

It's been running fine for several months now, but since I've re-installed the node_modules folder I got this error.

**Module not found: Can't resolve 'final-form-material-ui/dist' in '....'**

package.json

```
...
"dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^3.9.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^3.0.2",
...
```

In the component, i use:

```
import {TextField, Input} from 'final-form-material-ui/dist';
```

And in the node_modules/final-form-material-ui/dist folder I do have the TextField.d.ts and the Input.d.ts files.

Any clues?

Comment: Why are you using `from 'final-form-material-ui/dist'` ? instead of `from '@material-ui/core'` ?

Comment: tssss.... somehow that slipped in (can't think of why...) any way solved, thnx !

Comment: I can put a full answer for this

Comment: It is webstorm's refactoring that caused this, it actually changed: 'react-final-form' to 'react-final-form/dist'... well good to know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import the right package from `@material-ui/core`.

```
import {TextField, Input} from '@material-ui/core';
```

Answer (score 0):

changed as suggested / asked / queried by HRK44

```
import {TextField, Input} from '@material-ui/core';
```